# In python adding empty list to dataframe column by using lambda raises valueError

Tags: python, pandas

I was able to reproduce the error on synthetic data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': [datetime.now(), datetime.now(), datetime.now(), datetime.now()],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3]);
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
                    'E': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4']},
                   index=[0,1,2,3]);

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['A', 'A']);

def getList(row):
    r = [];
    if row["A"] == "A1": r.append("test-01");
    if row["B"] == "B1": r.append("test-02");
    if row["B"] == "B2": r.append("test-03");
    return r;

df["NEW_COLUMN"] = df.apply(lambda row: getList(row), axis = 1);
```

Original post: I would like to create a new column in pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions. The value of the new column should be list. However I got "ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified." in case of empty list.

```
def getList(p_row):
  r = [];
  if p_row["field1"] > 0: r.append("x");
  ...
  return r;

df["new_list_field"] = df.apply(lambda row: getList(row), axis = 1);
```

The complete error:

> ValueError              Traceback (most recent call last)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in
>   create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)    4636     try:
>   -> 4637         blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)    4638         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in
>   form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)    4728     if len(object_items) > 0:
>   -> 4729         object_blocks = _simple_blockify(object_items, np.object_)    4730         blocks.extend(object_blocks)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in
>   _simple_blockify(tuples, dtype)    4758     """
>   -> 4759     values, placement = _stack_arrays(tuples, dtype)    4760
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in
>   _stack_arrays(tuples, dtype)    4822     for i, arr in enumerate(arrays):
>   -> 4823         stacked[i] = _asarray_compat(arr)    4824
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape
>   (195)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError              Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 df["new_list_field"] = df.apply(lambda row: getList(row), axis = 1);
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)    4875 
>   f, axis,    4876                         reduce=reduce,
>   -> 4877                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)    4878             else:    4879                 return
>   self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)    4988                 index = None    4989 
>   -> 4990             result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)    4991             result.columns = res_index    4992
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   **init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>       328                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
>       329         elif isinstance(data, dict):
>   --> 330             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>       331         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
>       332             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
>       459             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
>       460 
>   --> 461         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>       462 
>       463     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)    6171     axes = [_ensure_index(columns), _ensure_index(index)]    6172 
>   -> 6173     return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)    6174     6175
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in
>   create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)    4640
>   return mgr    4641     except ValueError as e:
>   -> 4642         construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)    4643     4644
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in
>   construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)    4604
>   raise e    4605     if block_shape[0] == 0:
>   -> 4606         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
>
> 4607     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices
>   imply {1}".format(    4608         passed, implied))
>
> ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.

Comment: welcome to SO!, can you provide the `dataframe` in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) manner.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot share the original data. It is a million records dataset merged from several datasources and contains very sensitive information. Having index on 2 columns. Unfortunately cannot reproduce it with sample data because that code works properly. Also tried to create a copy of a slice of the large dataset, but got the same error message.

Comment: Data comes from rdbms via odbc, also from csv files. Made a small chunk with copy() and kept only few fields.
ID                        int64
PAYMENT_ID              float64
CREDIT_FL                object
TRX_MSG                  object
CALENDAR_DATE    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
Object type fields should be strings.
With CALENDAR_DATE field raises ValueError Traceback (most recent call last). Without that fields it works. Something might be wrong with the datatypes although I could already create few fields with a simple condition and  with int and string type.

Comment: One sincere advice: can you try not to use semicolons in python scripts? They don't do anything in Python, don't throw errors but make code clumsier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up making a list of lists, turning that into a `pd.Series()` and assigning it to a new column. a dictionary `key2list` returns variable-length lists as values:

```
new_col_list = []

for _, row in my_df.iterrows():
    new_col_list.append(key2list[row[u'key']])

my_df[u'new_col'] = pd.Series(new_col_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

The length of the output of this function varies from row to row, but you cannot assign lists of unequal lengths to a new pandas column. You can verify this through:

```
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    print(getList(row))
```

An alternative would be converting the output to a string instead:

```
def getListString(row):
    r = ''
    if row["A"] == "A1": r+="test-01"
    if row["B"] == "B1": r+="test-02"
    if row["B"] == "B2": r+="test-03"
    return r
```

Comment: df["C"] = df['C'].dt.date fixed the issue. No clue why :-(